# How to trigger useSprings() multiple animations, back to back

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-three-fiber, react-spring

First started animating using **@react-spring/three**'s `useSpring()`, and then got `useSprings()` working, but only for one animation at a time still.

1. How do I queue one animation after another?
2. Is there a better way to detect when an animation is done than `.idle` and `!.isAnimating`?
3. How to avoid manually queueing the animations?

Currently viewable at https://demo.robotjs.org/

Setup Springs:

```js
const [springs, api] = useSprings(
  1,
  () => ({
    jointAngles: jointAngles,
    config: {
      easing: easings.easeInOutQuad
    }
  }),
  []
)
```

Start a robot animation:

```js
api.start({
  jointAngles: randomJointAngles()
})
```

Check if it is done:

```js
if ( springs[0].jointAngles.idle ) {
  // end animation trigger
}
```

---

This is how I think it should be setup, but not sure how to trigger the different moves `move[i]` without `api.start()`.

```js
const moves = [
  ...
]

const [springs, api] = useSprings(
  moves.length,
  i => (
    {
      jointAngles: moves[i],
      config: {
        easing: easings.easeInOutQuad
      }
    }
  ),
  []
)
```

My intuition tells me to handle the animation states outside of `useSprings()`, or try out `useChain()`.